# openSSL SHA3 Selfsigned key , get it signed by ca or sign with own pki key

Tags: ssl, cryptography, openssl

I like to use [CACert](http://cacert.org) normally for keys.

however was going to mess with **SHA3-512** in test. 
for the Decreased attack vectors.  (for the moment their software doesn't yet support this)
my csr file spece'd **sha3**. however *sha2* out. 
Openssl supports making shaw 3 keys.

Make self-signed keys great. --many guides for it. 
*openssl req -new -config _com.cnf -keyout _com.key -out _com.csr*

[ req ]

**default_bits = 4096**

prompt = no

encrypt_key = no

**default_md = SHA-3**

distinguished_name = dn

req_extensions = req_ext

[ dn ]

CN = ----

emailAddress = ----------------------

O = -------------------------

L = ----

ST = -----

C = US

0.OU= IT/MIS

countryName_default = US

[ req_ext ]

subjectAltName = DNS:-----------

x509 EMAIL/SSL key PKI key is from CACERT. (PFX/P12)  , by chance with openssl

My-server-SSL (selfsigned) Ultra-paranoid strength....

**Sign with Personal x509 KEY.** or get signed by CA.

*I'm wondering if you can sign a self-signed key or get the pub ssl key signed.* 
by a CA, IE or an Assurer for the CA. ie wot CACERT.org. 
I'm wanting to test it and if claims are true take advantage of the enhanced security and harden my apps further.

Comment: `default_md = SHA-3` - grepping the OpenSSL source code, I don't see where `SHA-3` is valid.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Try and use tags with many followers for future (on topic) questions, many more precise ones will still not reach many. Replaced 3 tags with [tag:cryptography].